# How to force desktop mode in Wordpress when viewing in mobile phone?

Tags: wordpress, mobile, user-agent

I would like to ask how to force desktop behaviour in wordpress with mobile phones?

I have tried some plugins (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack/, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mobile-smart/, etc.) with no success.

I switched to desktop mode user agent on my phone with no success.

Wordpress site still shows in some mobile mode. Layout is different and some elements are even missing.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, it all depends upon two things, first the theme you choose and then on mobile browser.

Let's discuss theme first, if its responsive theme, then it surely will change the layout of site and even might miss some div blocks.

And now a days most of the themes are responsive, they automatically adjust to mobile browser, even wordpress default theme twenty eleven and twelve are responsive.

Secondly, most of high end mobile browser are made to change the look of site, just to facilitate users and irritate developers (lol)

Well, i would suggest, please check it this theme responsive, if yes, make it static.

Comment: Thanks, I finally found out that theme responsivness could by disabled in theme settings.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out how to do this. I found out accidentally that when you setup domain forwarding (and use masking) in GoDaddy, it will always show the desktop version of the site when you visit the domain on a phone. Now, you don't want to buy a different domain for every website you want to be "non-mobile". So, simply setup a sub-domain and forward it to your website (using masking). When you visit that subdomain on a phone, it will show the full desktop version. Hope this helps you as much as it helped me :)